# Adding dataset for measuremnts to kalman filter

Tags: python, loops, kalman-filter

I am implementing the Kalman filter and I have a data set in mf4 format for the measurements. I have 6 measurements and each of them contains 1000 values, I am implementing a loop of 100 for the Kalman filter but as I am new to Kalman filter and python so I am not sure that the procedure I am following is correct or not. My question is that when I run the loop for the measurements in the update step for prediction of next state then all these 1000 values will be used and if it is so then the result might not be appropriate. Kindly suggest any solution, please.
My code is:

```
class KF:
# initialization of variables
   def __init__(self, a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i): 
       # do initizatoin steps

       #x = [a,b,c,d,e,f]

       # a = yaw rate, b = float angle, c = offset between road and vehicle, d = curvature, e = angle 
       # b/w ego vehicles direction of motion and the road curvature tangent, f = lane width
    
   def predict(self, dt, u):

   # using equations do the predict step
   # u = [g,h,i]
   # g = front angle wheel, h = longitudinal velocity, i = acceleration
   # dt = time step

    def update(self, y):

   # using equations of update step
   # y1 = yaw rate, y2 = acceleration, y3 = curvature, y4 = angle b/w vehicle axis and lane,
   # y5 = lane width, y6 = offset b/w road and vehicle

# Main code:

kf = KF(a = random.random(), b = random.random(), c = random.random(), d = random.random(), e= random.random(), f = random.random(), g= random.random(), h= random.random(), I = random.random())
variance = 0.1 ** 2

DT = 0.1
number = 100

for step in range(number):                         

   kf.predict(dt=DT, tmp=np.array([kf.g,kf.h,kf.i]))   
 
   cc = np.empty(6, dtype=object)

   meas_y1 = efficient.get('Car.Yaw') + np.random.randn() * np.sqrt(variance)
   meas_y2 = efficient.get('Car.ay_1') + np.random.randn() * np.sqrt(variance)
   meas_y3 = efficient.get('Car.Curv') + np.random.randn() * np.sqrt(variance)
   meas_y4 = efficient.get('Car.LongSlope') + np.random.randn() * np.sqrt(variance)
   meas_y5 = efficient.get('Car.Width') + np.random.randn() * np.sqrt(variance)
   meas_y6 = efficient.get('Car.tMidLane') + np.random.randn() * np.sqrt(variance) 

   cc[:]= [meas_y1, meas_y2, meas_y3, meas_y4, meas_y5, meas_y6]
   
   kf.update(y= cc)
```